# Icinga2 icingaWeb2 : Can not enrol window host to Centos master but no issue on other Centos server

Tags: icinga2, icingaweb2

I had Icinga2 and icingaweb2 (with director) are all set up perfectly fine on Centos,,, I could write a bash script to auto enrol other hosts (centos and Linux) to be monitored by this IcingaWeb... But now i would like to have Windows client to be monitored as well..follow L https://www.linuxtechi.com/add-remote-linux-windows-host-icinga-2-monitoring/... But when i did try i kept get the error from the master as :

```
[2018-07-20 09:48:55 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: Received certificate request for CN 'client.domain' signed by our CA.
[2018-07-20 09:48:55 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: The certificate for CN 'client.domain' cannot be renewed yet.
[2018-07-20 09:49:55 +0000] warning/JsonRpcConnection: API client disconnected for identity 'client.domain'
[2018-07-20 09:50:30 +0000] information/ApiListener: New client connection for identity 'client.domain' from [10.2.13.227]:56826 (certificate validation failed: code 18: self signed certificate)
[2018-07-20 09:50:30 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: Received certificate request for CN 'client.domain' not signed by our CA.
[2018-07-20 09:50:30 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: Sending certificate response for CN 'client.domain' to endpoint 'client.domain' (auto-signing ticket).
[2018-07-20 09:50:30 +0000] warning/JsonRpcConnection: API client disconnected for identity 'client.domain'
[2018-07-20 09:50:38 +0000] information/ApiListener: New client connection for identity 'client.domain' from [10.2.13.227]:56843 (no Endpoint object found for identity)
[2018-07-20 09:50:38 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: Received certificate request for CN 'client.domain' signed by our CA.
[2018-07-20 09:50:38 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: The certificate for CN 'client.domain' cannot be renewed yet.
```

I suspected issue on certificate but i have no ideal how to fix..

Here is at the client.domain log:

```
[2018-07-20 10:13:33 -0000] warning/JsonRpcConnection: API client disconnected for identity 'master.domain'
[2018-07-20 10:13:33 -0000] warning/JsonRpcConnection: API client disconnected for identity 'master.domain'
[2018-07-20 10:13:33 -0000] warning/ApiListener: Removing API client for endpoint 'master.domain'. 0 API clients left.
[2018-07-20 10:13:33 -0000] warning/ApiListener: Removing API client for endpoint 'master.domain'. 0 API clients left.
[2018-07-20 10:17:57 -0000] information/ApiListener: Adding new listener on port '5665'
[2018-07-20 10:17:57 -0000] information/CheckerComponent: 'checker' started.
[2018-07-20 10:17:57 -0000] information/ConfigItem: Activated all objects.
[2018-07-20 10:18:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #5 (ApiListener, SyncQueue) items: 0, rate:  0/s (0/min 0/5min 0/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:18:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #4 (ApiListener, RelayQueue) items: 0, rate: 0.183333/s (11/min 11/5min 11/15min);

[2018-07-20 10:22:57 -0000] information/ConfigObject: Dumping program state to file 'C:\ProgramData\icinga2\var/lib/icinga2/icinga2.state'
[2018-07-20 10:23:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #5 (ApiListener, SyncQueue) items: 0, rate:  0/s (0/min 0/5min 0/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:23:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #4 (ApiListener, RelayQueue) items: 0, rate: 0.5/s (30/min 152/5min 152/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:27:57 -0000] information/ConfigObject: Dumping program state to file 'C:\ProgramData\icinga2\var/lib/icinga2/icinga2.state'
[2018-07-20 10:28:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #4 (ApiListener, RelayQueue) items: 0, rate: 0.5/s (30/min 150/5min 302/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:28:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #5 (ApiListener, SyncQueue) items: 0, rate:  0/s (0/min 0/5min 0/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:32:57 -0000] information/ConfigObject: Dumping program state to file 'C:\ProgramData\icinga2\var/lib/icinga2/icinga2.state'
[2018-07-20 10:33:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #5 (ApiListener, SyncQueue) items: 0, rate:  0/s (0/min 0/5min 0/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:33:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #4 (ApiListener, RelayQueue) items: 0, rate: 0.5/s (30/min 150/5min 452/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:37:57 -0000] information/ConfigObject: Dumping program state to file 'C:\ProgramData\icinga2\var/lib/icinga2/icinga2.state'
[2018-07-20 10:38:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #4 (ApiListener, RelayQueue) items: 0, rate: 0.5/s (30/min 144/5min 444/15min);
[2018-07-20 10:38:06 -0000] information/WorkQueue: #5 (ApiListener, SyncQueue) items: 0, rate:  0/s (0/min 0/5min 0/15min);
```

As you can see.. it seemed the master log only the issue one.. so any suggestions?

Comment: I had been trying to use icinga2-V2.8.4 and V2.9 on Windows and still issue remain.

Comment: How did you generate the Certificate?

Comment: @cflinspach thanks for reply.. i used 1. run on master with icinga2 pki ticket --cn client.domain .. and at the client i push that number that i got to a icinga tool .. as per https://www.linuxtechi.com/add-remote-linux-windows-host-icinga-2-monitoring/ .. i know that it asked to add host by hand after but.. for Linux.. no need to.. so i don't think we need to do.. we would like to manage in the Icinga Web.. FYI.. i had client API user and it works fine on Linux..

Answer (score 0):

All.. i got an update.. now the issue is not only occurred on Window anymore.. Now with the new enrolment on Centos7, i got this error too
--> log : [2018-08-01 09:15:12 +0000] information/ApiListener: Sending replay log for endpoint 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform' in zone 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'.
[2018-08-01 09:15:12 +0000] information/ApiListener: Finished sending replay log for endpoint 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform' in zone 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'.
[2018-08-01 09:15:12 +0000] information/ApiListener: Finished syncing endpoint 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform' in zone 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'.
[2018-08-01 09:16:14 +0000] information/JsonRpcConnection: No messages for identity 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform' have been received in the last 60 seconds.
[2018-08-01 09:16:14 +0000] warning/JsonRpcConnection: API client disconnected for identity 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'
[2018-08-01 09:16:14 +0000] warning/JsonRpcConnection: API client disconnected for identity 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'
[2018-08-01 09:16:14 +0000] warning/ApiListener: Removing API client for endpoint 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'. 0 API clients left.
[2018-08-01 09:16:14 +0000] warning/ApiListener: Removing API client for endpoint 'dev-graphite-1a-0.acommercedev.platform'. 0 API clients left.

Something wrong with my Master API ?

Comment: updated : i got all the Linux works only Window,, now trying to configure nrpe to get remote host disk and memory check..